# Show the power series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^{n-1}$ diverges when $|x|>R$.

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, divergent-series

Suppose that the power series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n$$ has radius of convergence $R$. Then the power series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^{n-1}$$ diverges if $|x|>R$.

**Attempt:** I can show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |na_nx^{n-1}|$ diverges by comparison test, but how do I show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^{n-1}$ diverges also?

Comment: The comment of the other user about the limit comparison test that was deleted.

Comment: @rtybase nope. This requires to prove the other direction also (direction of divergence, which is THE question for this post.)

Comment: From $\sum a_n x^n < \infty, |x|<R \Leftrightarrow \sum na_n x^{n-1} < \infty, |x|<R$, then the problem of divergence of $\sum na_n x^{n-1}, |x|>R$ is equivalent with divergence of $\sum a_n x^n, |x|>R$.

$$\Rightarrow$$ If $\sum a_n x^n < \infty, |x|<R$ then (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series#Differentiation_and_integration) $\sum na_n x^{n-1} < \infty, |x|<R$ - derivative is applied.

$$\Leftarrow$$ $\sum na_n x^{n-1} < \infty, |x|<R$ then (same article) $\sum a_n x^n < \infty, |x|<R$ - integration is applied.

Comment: Yes, how do you prove that? Since I can prove the direction of convergence, here I'm asking for divergence.

Comment: I updated my comment ... plus the logical trick of $ p\iff q\equiv \neg p\iff \neg q$

Comment: @rtybase nice trick! But how would you prove by given $f$ diverges then $f'$ diverges?

Comment: Divergence of $f$ becomes equivalent to the divergence of $f'$. If you prove $f$ diverges - you're done with $f'$ too...

Comment: @rtybase I understand the trick you showed, but given only $f$ diverges, how do you prove that $f'$ also diverges from that?

Comment: not using contrapositive, but direct proof.

Comment: You don't have to, $f - \text{converges } \Leftrightarrow f' - \text{converges}$ I already proved. That means negations are also equivalent, just prove $f - \text{diverges}$ and that automatically applies to $f'$, otherwise you can reduce it to a proof by contradiction. Why would you want a hard way when there is an easy one? :)

Comment: @rtybase Because I really want to know if it works by proving directly. (Since I was really stuck there, I wonder if it is possible.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Showing that it diverges for $|x|>R$ is equivalent to showing that the radius of convergence $R'$ of the second power series is $\leq R$.

But $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} |na_{n}x^{n-1}| = \frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} |na_{n}x^{n}| \geq \frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} |a_{n}x^{n}|$ shows just that.

P.S.: in fact the other direction ($R' \geq R$) is more difficult to prove

Comment: Is the inequality on the right true?

Comment: It is certainly true if $a_n$ is nonnegative.

Comment: Corrected, i meant to consider the absolute values... which is what you are looking at for power series.

Comment: I've already showed that but I'm having trouble showing true without the absolutely value.

Comment: If this is absolutely diverging then $R' \leq R$ which means that for $x > R$ the sum will diverge because its main term $(a_{n}x_{0}^{n})$ is not bounded (when $x_{0}>R$, as per Abel's lemma).

Comment: This lemma defines the radius of convergence as $R = sup(\{|x_{0}|; (a_{n}x_{0}^{n}) bounded\})$ and then shows absolute converge of the series inside the open disc $D(0,R)$ and divergence outside of the closed disc (since the main term is not even bounded).

Comment: Can you explain why this would not be just conditionally convergent?

Comment: Because the main term wouldn't even be bounded (which is a necessary condition for - conditional or absolute - convergence, since a convergent series must have its main term converging toward $0$). The more interesting part of the exercise is to show absolute convergence inside $D(0,R)$

Comment: Are you claiming that in general if $\sum|a_n|$ diverges, then $\sum a_n$ cannot be convergent?

Comment: Btw you did not define $R$ correctly, i.e. even if each term is bounded, it does not guarantee that the sum of the series converges, such as sum of infinitely many (+1) gives you infinity.

Comment: "A series is said to be conditionally convergent if and only if it is convergent, the series of its positive terms diverges to positive infinity and the series of its negative terms diverges to negative infinity." So even if the main terms are not bounded you can still have a conditionally convergent series.

Comment: By main term I mean $a_{n}$, not the partial sums $\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}$ which the proposition you quoted is referring to...

Comment: In order to prove it: let $S_{n}$ be the partial sum of a converging series. Then $(S_{n})$ is Cauchy and thus $|S_{n+1} - S_{n}| = |a_{n+1}|$ converges to $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Given that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n$ has a radius of convergence $R$, then we have from the [Root Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test#Test) that

$$R=\frac{1}{\limsup_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}}$$

Inasmuch as $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{n}=1$, then the radius of convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^{n-1}$ is

$$\frac{1}{\limsup_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{|na_n|}}=\frac{1}{\limsup_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}}=R$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: so you are getting the radius of convergence for both of them and show that those are the same. Would you say that the approach of using comparison test on the two series is just not going to work?